# In what order is the serverless file evaluated?

Tags: serverless-framework

I have tried to find out in what order the statements of the serverless file are evaluated (maybe it is more common to say that 'variables are resolved').

I haven't been able to find any information about this and to some extent it makes working with serverless feel like a guessing game for me.

As an example, the latest surprise I got was when I tried to run:

```
$ sls deploy
```

```
serverless.yaml

useDotenv: true

provider:
  stage: ${env:stage}
  region: ${env:region}
```

```
.env

region=us-west-1
stage=dev
```

I got an error message stating that env is not available at the time when stage is resolved. This was surprising to me since I have been able to use env to resolve other variables in the provider section, and there is nothing in the syntax to indicate that stage is resolved earlier.

In what order is the serverless file evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

In effect you've created a circular dependency. `Stage` is special because it is needed to identify which `.env` file to load. `${env:stage}` is being resolved from `${stage}.env`, but Serverless needs to know what `${stage}` is in order to find `${stage}.env` etc.

This is why it's evaluated first.

Stage (and region, actually) are both optional CLI parameters. In your `serverless.yml` file what you're setting is a default, with the CLI parameter overriding it where different.

Example:

```yaml
provider:
  stage: staging
  region: ca-central-1
```

Running `serverless deploy --stage prod --region us-west-2` will result in `prod` and `us-west-2` being used for stage and region (respectively) for that deployment.

I'd suggest removing any variable interpolation for `stage` and instead setting a default, and overriding via CLI when needed.

Then `dotenv` will know which environment file to use, and complete the rest of the template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was very helpful. Now I understand the example I mentioned much better. Is there any simple answer to the more general question 'In what order is the serverless file evaluated?'

Comment: It's not evaluated, it's not a program - it's a configuration file. The serverless framework transforms the serverless.yml file into cloudformation, and then (inside aws) cloudformation creates a directed, acyclic graph and provisions infrastructure in order.